# From Telerik grid to Kendo grid, Image

Tags: asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I was told to change the Telerik grid, in a web page, to Kendo grid.

And for that, there is a column that is showing an image, depending on if it has any errors:

```
columns.Template(x => x.HasError)
   .ClientTemplate("<img src=<#= HasError ? \"" 
   + Url.Content("~/Content/images/109_AllAnnotations_Error_24x24_72.png") + "\" : \"" 
   + Url.Content("~/Content/images/109_AllAnnotations_Default_24x24_72.png") + "\" #> title=\"<#= LastErrorMessage #>\"").Width(100);
})
```

This line did just fine in the Telerik grid, but in the Kendo Grid, it gives me a "400 Bad request".

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the template syntax from **<#= #>** to just **#= #**. This is the only difference when it comes to client templates.